# HTML Table hide Column doesn't work anymore?

Tags: html, css

I hide columns in a table if it is needed. I used the style="display:none" within a  - Tag.

It worked for a while, but actually it doesn't work anymore...

Example code:

```
<table width="100%">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="auto">
        <col width="auto">
        <col width="auto">
        <col width="auto" style="display: none">
        <col width="auto" style="display: none">
        <col width="auto">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th......
</table>
```

Comment: As per [W3 Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/colgroup), styling `<colgroup>`, `<col>` is now limited to `background-color`, `border`, `width` and `visibility`. Also have a look at: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/columns.html

Comment: `visibility: collapse` helped, but it it makes some crazy things sometimes... thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably worked in IE 7, because IE 7 had a wrong implementation of column properties. According to the CSS 2.1 specification, clause [7.1 Columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns), the only properties that apply to `col` elements (i.e. have an effect when set on them) are `background`, `border`, `visibility` (only when the value `collapse` is set), and `width`. This bug was fixed in IE 8.

Thus, you can set `visibility: collapse` instead, as suggested in a comment. If you find this approach infeasible for some reason, you can set `display` on the cells instead. Making all cells of a column not displayed naturally means that the column is not shown at all. Since the simplest way of doing this is not supported by old versions of IE, you can still keep the settings you have now (setting `display: none` on `col` is not illegal in CSS, it is just defined so that it has no effect):

```css
tr > :nth-child(4), tr > :nth-child(5) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col style="display: none">
<col style="display: none">
<col>
    <tr>
        <th>a <th>b <th>c <th>d <th>e <th>f
</table>
```

I have added the `border` attribute just for clarity. I have removed the `width="auto"` attributes, since they are invalid and have no effect. Setting the widths is a different issue.

Comment: Thx alot, it works. But I am looking something different. But you actually answered the question so :) its ok.